# Eclipse Classic: Properties View Not Correctly Updating on UI Element Click

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm very new to Android (started yesterday) and so far so good, but one problem I'm having is that when I click on a UI element ("form widget") in the graphical layout view, the properties window doesn't correctly update to reflect the element I have selected.

Am I doing something wrong? I tried restarting Eclipse. Perhaps, there is another way to get the properties window to reflect the currently selected UI element?

-- Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the graphical mode, there are often overlapping UI elements. So, when you select something, it may actually be selecting the topmost element. To select the object you want, try selecting it from the properties window itself (such as the layout or the view).

Comment: this worked for me. But i have one more instance of eclipse where if i open the same project will be able to click the items and properties view gets updated! So the problem still remains the same. Must be some bug the ADT. This problem started after i updated ADT to latest version 10.0.1